# MQTT connect over tcp in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mqtt

I cannot connect to the TCP address and that code only connect to websocket. How can i convert my code to connect tcp address?

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('testMQTT', function ($scope) {
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("10.218.68.81", Number(1883), "/Sensors/PIM-1/SensorData", "pim1");
    client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
        console.log("Connection Lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
    client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
        console.log("Message Arrived: " + message.payloadString);
        $scope.$apply();
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
        console.log(jsonObject);
    }
    function onConnect() {
        $scope.Message = "Connected !";
        console.log("connected");
        var subscribeOptions = {
            qos: 2, // QoS
            invocationContext: {
                foo: true
            }, // Passed to success / failure callback
            onSuccess: onSuccessCallback,
            onFailure: onFailureCallback,
            timeout: 10
        };
        client.subscribe("/Sensors/PIM-1/SensorData", subscribeOptions);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    function onSuccessCallback() {}
    function onFailureCallback() {}
    $scope.Messages = "Connecting !";
    // Connect the client, providing an onConnect callback
    client.connect({
        onSuccess: onConnect
    });
})
```

[image]

Comment: I think the issue is with your mqtt broker not supporting websockets - I don't believe you can make a "raw" TCP connection in a browser anyway (websocket, by the way, is simply a full-duplex communication channel over a single TCP connection - so your question makes little sense)

Comment: Thanks i solved it.

Comment: super secret solution is it :p

Comment: Post your answer so future SO researchers can benefit from your findings.

Comment: How did you solve it. can you share

Comment: used port 80 for tcp